# Manual ALB Creation for AWS EKS Fargate

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-fargate, aws-alb

How can we create application load balancer in aws eks fargate manually instead of using alb ingress controller?

1. I was able to create and associate the Application Load balancer with fargate pods. However, is there a way to automatically register new pods as targets in ALB.
2. When using targets as IP in the target groups, I cannot find a way to define an IP range. It only takes individual IP's, in which case I need to manually add the targets every time a new pod comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is usually done using the ingress object. Sorry if I ask but is there a reason for which you can't use the ALB ingress which would give you that out of the box? Note that there were some limitations in the past (e.g. one ALB per ingress object etc) but we have just made available a new version of the ALB ingress that overcomes some of those limitations: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-aws-load-balancer-controller/

Comment: Hi, Thanks
Yes, the new AWS Load Balancer Controller resloves my issue.